# Transpose dataframe withe many columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

this is my dataframe schema :

```
 `root
 |-- customerid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- groupe1: string (nullable = false)
 |-- groupe2: string (nullable = false)
 |-- groupe3: string (nullable = false)
```

this is a part of my dataframe

```
+----------------+--------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+
|customerid|     |  event | group1             | group2       |    groupe3     |
+----------------+--------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+
|     4454545    |        |[aaa,0,0,0]         |[555,0,88,0,0]| [3190,0,0,0,0] |
|     8878787787 |2019    |[bbb,0,fff,0,0]     | [420,0,0,0,0]| [9580,0,0,0,0] |
|     12555888888|2019    |[cccc,0,fff,eee,0]  | [385,0,0,0,0]| [4995,0,0,0,0] |
+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

i tried this code :

```
val zip = udf((xs: Seq[String], ys: Seq[String], zs: Seq[String]) => (xs, ys, zs).zipped.toSeq)

df.printSchema

val df4=df.withColumn("vars", explode(zip($"groupe1", $"groupe2",$"groupe3"))).select(
   $"customerid", $"event",
   $"vars._1".alias("groupe1"), $"vars._2".alias("groupe2"),$"vars._2".alias("groupe3"))
```

I got this error :

```
cannot resolve 'UDF(groupe1, groupe2, groupe3)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array<string> type, however, '`groupe1`' is of string type. argument 2 requires array<string> type, however, '`groupe2`' is of string type. argument 3 requires array<string> type, however, '`groupe3`' is of string type.;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of column group1,group2,group3 is string so it’s incompatible with your udf which has a Seq[string] parameter.Maybe you should change the input of the udf to string type.

Comment: i changed to val zip = udf((xs: String, ys: String, zs: String) => (xs, ys, zs).zipped.toSeq) but i got this error  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Char is not supported

Comment: After you changed input type to string ,variable xs,ys,zs are string now,it’s not supported to use zipped operation on string tuple (xs,ys,zs),so,i guess you need to split xs,ys,zs to seq before using zipped on the tuple of them.

Comment: like this ?  :          val df4=df.withColumn("vars", explode(zip((split($"groupe1",","), (split($"groupe3",","),(split($"groupe2",",")))).select(
   $"customerid", $"event",
   $"vars._1".alias("groupe1"), $"vars._2".alias("groupe3"),$"vars._2".alias("groupe2"))

Comment: Yes,this is an option.And also you can change the udf like this:  (xs.split(“,”),ys.split(“,”),zs.split(“,”)).zipped.toSeq